# My object is missing when i turn on alpha

Tags: rendering, image, transparency

I have my camera set up to render my object with a transparent background in PNG format. But when i enable transparency, I get nothing rendered other than an empty PNG.

These are my settings for blender render shown in the image attached (may need to open image in another tab to see it larger)[image]:

Also as a side note, is there such an option in cycles render, as I could never find the option to render with transparent background so had to resort to blender render.

Comment: I assume that you didn't link the Composit node in Node Editor, however, a blend file is very helpful here, to quickly target it. You can try to upload it [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend)

Comment: @LeonCheung http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33575 here you go. Warning it won't have good performance on poor PC specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your file, the problem is you are trying to use Cycles material node as BI material node, which cannot happen.

[image]

Solution:

1. Switch the Render engine from **Blender Render** to **Cycles**;
2. If you want to render it in Blender Render (BI), you have to either toggle off the **Use Node** button, or create a new material node readable for BI.

I assume the first one is your better option, since it seems you sort of mis-switched the engine at some point (or the material node is appended from anywhere else).

Comment: So which is better quality between the two types of renders?

Comment: Cycles by far. Actually, I'm not allowed to voice my opinion (curses!) but Cycles generally has more solid and realistic images.